# Multiple intersection tables vs multiple joins

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I have a hierarchical relationship between my tables, with the children having foreign keys referring back to their parent ids (assuming `id` is the primary key for each table):

`Department` has many `Category Group`s
`Category Group` has many `Category`(-ies)
`Category` has many `Sub-Category`(-ies)
`Sub-Category` has many `Attribute`s.

Now, all these entities except for `Attribute`s are optional meaning if I don't select anything on my hierarchical cascading dropdown based UI, I need to display the `Attribute`s that belong to all `Department`s, if I only select a `Department` then I need to display `Attribute`s that belong to all `Category Group`s belonging to that `Department` and so on.

Obviously, one option to implement it is to do a inner join between all the tables to get to `Attribute`. For instance, if nothing is selected it will be:
`Department` inner join `Category Group`
inner join `Category`
inner join `Sub-Category`
inner join `Attribute`
to show all the attributes belonging to all departments.

The other thought in my head is to have intersection/relation mapping table(s) -
`DepartmentAttributeRelation` which has foreign keys to `Department` and `Attribute`,
`CategoryGroupAttributeRelation` which has foreign keys to `CategoryGroup` and `Attribute` and so on.
This will enable direct search to get to the `Attribute`s given any entity.

My question is - Are there any downsides to the second approach above or are there any better approaches to solve this?

Comment: Could you provide ER diagrams, however crude?

Comment: Do you happen to know an easy way to generate those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the problem with the inner join? Create a view so you don't ever have to see or write the ugly multi-join query again.

The alternative's first and more important drawback is that you can have inconsistencies i.e. you can have data in those "join tables" that could potentially contradict themselves, i.e. insertion anomalies are possible. You would need to write code to prevent those anomalies from occurring.

Keep in mind, though, that sometimes when one believes a hierarchy will forever be at much, say, 4 levels deep, then a requirement comes around when a sub-sub-category is needed and the fixed level hierarchy design breaks. A future-proof solution where there can be an unknown depth of levels of hierarchy and only the "leaf" elements can have attributes is a matter of another question and another answer.

Comment: My main concern with inner join is that will it be slow when I make a REST call and do this as opposed to a direct look up? Would it be possible to give a simple example of the inconsistency? I am assuming this will only be specific to the join table?    
For the last paragraph - what are your thoughts on having a single Category table with a parent id column referencing itself to characterize the hierarchy and the Attribute table always refers to the leaf id?

Comment: @linuxNoob Don't think beforehand that it will be slow. If PKs and FKs are in place the RDBMS will do the job is was designed for, unless you're talking an inordinate number of rows when the problem begins to be a job for a noSQL database.

Comment: @linuxNoob An example of inconsistency is that you can insert into the `CategoryGroupAttributeRelation` table a relationship that is not present in the `DepartmentAttributeRelation` so lookups at different levels would have contradictory results. In a perfect world not you're app not you will insert that, but errors happens and the database will not complain. In the first design that will not be possible because there's a single route to every attribute.

Comment: Do you mind sharing some insights on the extensibility aspect as well? (the last paragraph of your answer)? Like how to go about designing that?

Comment: Also, this data will be seeded once and maybe updated on some schedule (once a week or so) by a program. If I ensure that I am inserting the data in all the relevant tables then unless someone directly inserts data into those tables I don't think I should have inconsistencies but I do see what you're saying.

Comment: @linuxNoob About the extensibility, it would be god to ask in a separate question because it wanders off the original problem, also many people could benefit from that question (if it's not been already asked and answered).

Comment: I've posted the other question here - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/415139/extensible-hierarchical-database-design if you want to take a look, although it has been heavily downvoted and I am not sure why.